# Undefined variable CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i'm having an issue with my php. I've been using codeigniter and the following code is returning me this error message:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined variable: item
Filename: views/banner.php
Line Number: 37
```

My controller is as following:

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();

    $this->auth->check();

    $this->load->database();
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->model('banner_model');
}

public function index()
{
    $dados['banner'] = $this->banner_model->recuperar_todos_banners();

    $this->load_view("banner", $dados);
}
```

My view:

```
    <? foreach ($banner as $item):?>
       <tr>
          <td><?=$item->chave?></td>
          <td><?=$item->imagem?></td>
          <td><?=$item->descricao?></td>
          <td><?=$item->link?></td>
          <td>
             <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span>
             </button>
          </td>
       </tr>
    <? endforeach; ?>
```

I tested both variables using var_dump. The purpose of this code is to access a MySQL database and store the result in an array. The $banner variable is working fine and all the data is there so each position is occupied by objects, each object being a table row.

I know this question has been asked before on StackOverflow but I still couldn't figure out what's going on exactly.

Comment: are short tags enabled? If not, do `<?php echo` rather than `<?=` same for `<?` do `<?php`

Comment: they are enabled, I tested it this way and it didn't work either.

Comment: Sorry. you were correct. I fixed only some of the tags and forgot others.

Comment: use                     <?php foreach ?>
                    <?php endforeach;?>

Comment: I take it that all is good then ;-)

Comment: You're welcome  Tomás, glad to have been of help, *cheers*

Comment: someone posted an answer. I should probably be doing that. @TomásDornasPerone to set the record straight ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii-: you better!!! otherwise this doesn't make sense

Comment: Is there a way I can mark this question as answered? haha
hmm, i guess i just did it, never mind!

Comment: @Vickel *Cheers* and I quoted your comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Me:

> *are short tags enabled? If not, do `<?php echo` rather than `<?=` same for `<?` do `<?php` –  Fred -ii- 23 mins ago"*

OP:

> *Sorry. you were correct. I fixed only some of the tags and forgot others. –  Tomás Dornas Perone"*

The issue was indeed short tags after all.

And a comment by Vickel, and I quote:

> *use `<?php foreach ?> <?php endforeach;?>` –  Vickel 4 mins ago"*

Answer (score 2):

See if **$banner** is multidimensional array, or debug using a test **foreach** in your controller, hit a **var_dump()** in both places of the **$item**.